# Select records from multiple tables within duration and fulfill conditions ordered by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables, i.e. `HeroAcademy`, `Hero`, and `HeroMission`. I want to select a list of **academyID** from 3 tables.

[image: hero tables]

- Those **academyID** selected must fulfill `isActive IS true` AND `lastSeen BETWEEN :start AND :end`.
- The selected **academyID** list must be unique (no duplicate academyID).
- Lastly, the academyID must be *ordered* by the `lastSeen` in its respective table.

I tried to search around for better solution. Temporarily, I am using: *(brief example)*

```
SELECT DISTINCT academyID FROM (
    SELECT academyID, lastSeen FROM HeroAcademy WHERE ... UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT academyID, lastSeen FROM Hero WHERE ... ORDER BY lastSeen UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT academyID, lastSeen FROM HeroMission WHERE ... ORDER BY lastSeen
) ORDER BY lastSeen
```

Are there any better solution? It seems my query are very basic and ultra-SLOW... looking forward for any genius query. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (academyID) academyID
FROM ( (SELECT DISTINCT ON (academyID) academyID, lastSeen
        FROM HeroAcademy
        WHERE ...
        ORDER BY academyID, lastSeen DESC
       ) UNION ALL
       (SELECT DISTINCT ON (academyID) academyID, lastSeen
        FROM Hero
        WHERE ...
        ORDER BY academyID, lastSeen DESC
       ) UNION ALL
       (SELECT DISTINCT ON (academyID) academyID, lastSeen
        FROM HeroMission
        WHERE ...
        ORDER BY academyID, lastSeen DESC
       )
      ) a
ORDER BY academyID, lastSeen;
```

Notes:

- Assuming no `WHERE` clauses, this can take advantage of indexes on `(academyId, lastSeen)` on each of the tables.
- Your query has multiple duplicate removal operations -- `union` and `select distinct` at two levels.
- I think `DISTINCT ON` does a better job of getting the most recent (or least recent) record.  Depending on the `WHERE` clause, it can take advantage of an index.

Comment: thanks, just realized there is a `distinct on` selector. Hmmm... in your opinion, is this a slow query? I am implement a paging feature too, thus need additional cycle for `COUNT(*)`, then just followed by `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. Is it better to create a "intermediate" table, which store the *academyID*, *lastSeen* and *AcademyHeroOrMission*, then I can easily `SELECT` from the table in simple query?

Comment: @BooYanJiong . . . In Postgres, `DISTINCT ON` is often faster than other ways of accomplishing the same thing.